# Check Wether A Changing Number is Lower or Higher Than it Last Was

Tags: python, counter, youtube-data-api

I am working on a python program that makes fun of Logan Paul in order to practice my python skills. Essentially my idea is to monitor Logan's sub count and if he loses a subscriber it makes fun of him. So far I have created a (bad) GUI that displays his subcount. How would I go about monitoring it and knowing if he has lost or gained a sub? As i proof of concept I would like it to do something like print "Lost" or "Gained" into the console. Im thinking that to do this I would have to store the previous number in memory using the `io` module but I don't think this is the best way.

Here is my code so far, the Comic Sans is for effect:

```
import urllib.request
import json
from tkinter import*

channelid = "UCG8rbF3g2AMX70yOd8vqIZg"
key = "AIzaSyDAOUFomRB1lxdb_fvSKKaG-FSZDRoVt_s"


def func(label2):
    data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id="+channelid+"&key="+key).read()
    subs = json.loads(data)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
    subc =("{:,d}".format(int(subs)))
    label2.config(text=subc)
    label2.update()
    root.after(10, lambda:func(label2))


root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x600")
root.title("yeetmeister")

label1 = Label(text="Logan Paul's Sub Count:", font=("Comic Sans MS", 45), fg="Brown")
label2 = Label(font=("Comic Sans MS", 45), fg="Red")

label1.place(x=10, y=20)
label2.place(x=10, y=130)

func(label2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want to keep this program running in the background, or do you want to fire it up every now and then to have it update the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a variable that will hold the subscribers in the previous check and perform comparison with the subscribers in the new check. So, you'll have to modify your program as follows:

```
import urllib.request
import json
from tkinter import*

channelid = "UCG8rbF3g2AMX70yOd8vqIZg"
key = "AIzaSyDAOUFomRB1lxdb_fvSKKaG-FSZDRoVt_s"
prevSubs = 0 # Variable to hold the subs from previous check
firstTime = True # Flag variable to avoid checking the first time due to lack of previous subscribers.

def func(label2,prevSubs, firstTime): # Change the signature here.
    data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id="+channelid+"&key="+key).read()
    subs = json.loads(data)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
    subc =("{:,d}".format(int(subs)))
    subs = int(subc.replace(',',''))
    # Comparisons to print the appropriate message
    if firstTime:
        print("Started monitoring...")
        firstTime = False
        pass
    else:
        if subs > prevSubs:
            print("Gained")
        elif subs < prevSubs:
            print("Lost")   
        else:
            pass
    prevSubs = subs # Update previous subs.
    label2.config(text=subc)
    label2.update()
    root.after(10, lambda:func(label2,prevSubs,firstTime)) # Add argument to 'func'.


root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x600")
root.title("yeetmeister")

label1 = Label(text="Logan Paul's Sub Count:", font=("Comic Sans MS", 45), fg="Brown")
label2 = Label(font=("Comic Sans MS", 45), fg="Red")

label1.place(x=10, y=20)
label2.place(x=10, y=130)

func(label2,prevSubs,firstTime) # Add new argument to 'func'.

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Awesome, works great, surprised you were nice enough to put time into a project that makes fun of logan paul.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a variable you remember, this way when you get the new sub count you can compare them

```
prev_subs = 0

def func():
    current_subs = subs #from api
    if prev_subs:
       if prev_subs > current_subs:
           #went down
       elif prev_subs < current_subs:
           #went up

    prev_subs = current_subs

while true: # just to continually refresh the data
    func(label2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add global variable:

```
import urllib.request
import json
from tkinter import*

channelid = "UCG8rbF3g2AMX70yOd8vqIZg"
key = "AIzaSyDAOUFomRB1lxdb_fvSKKaG-FSZDRoVt_s"

score = 0

def func(label2, label3):
    global score
    r = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id="+channelid+"&key="+key).read()
    # data = r.json()
    subs = json.loads(r.decode('utf-8'))["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
    newscore = int(subs)
    if(score < newscore):
        label3.config(text="UP" + " prev[ " + str(score) + "]")
        label3.config(fg="Green")
    else:
        if(score == newscore):
            label3.config(text="SAME" + " prev[ " + str(score) + "]")
            label3.config(fg="Blue")
        else:
            label3.config(text="DOWN" + " prev[ " + str(score) + "]")
            label3.config(fg="Red")
    score = newscore
    subc =("{:,d}".format(newscore))
    label2.config(text=subc)
    label2.update()
    root.after(10, lambda:func(label2, label3))


root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x600")
root.title("yeetmeister")

label1 = Label(text="Logan Paul's Sub Count:", font=("Comic Sans MS", 45), fg="Brown")
label2 = Label(font=("Comic Sans MS", 45), fg="Red")
label3 = Label(font=("Comic Sans MS", 45), fg="Blue")

label1.place(x=10, y=20)
label2.place(x=10, y=130)
label3.place(x=340, y=130)
label3.config(text="NO CHANGE")

func(label2, label3)

root.mainloop()
```